# Как увеличить значение ячейки в бд на +1?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, telebot

У меня есть код, который должен увеличить значение на 1, но место этого он лишь приравнивает значение моей ячейки данному числу (единице):

```
def up_level(self, level):
    """Апаем level"""
    with self.connection:
        return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `level` = 'level' + 1 WHERE `user_id` = ?", (level,))
```

Вызываю его следующим образом:

```
elif message.text == 'Увеличить уровень':
    db.up_level(message.from_user.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хитро! Вы повысили уровень на 1!')
```

Comment: Добрый день! а на SQL это правильно указать 'level' вместо  ` level ` ?

Comment: попробуйте ```self.cursor.execute("UPDATE subscriptions SET level = level + 1 WHERE user_id = ?", (level,))```

Comment: @FabioMendesSoares Спасибо вам большое! Мне стыдно, что я не заметил такую ошибку у себя! Все заработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С вопросом помог [Fabio Mendes Soares](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/252792/fabio-mendes-soares)!

Была ошибка в запросе с кавычками, вместо ' text ' необходимо использовать - `

Правильный запрос выглядит так:

```
("UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `level` = `level` + 1 WHERE `user_id` = ?", (level,))
```